# Android- remove URL percent symbols from string

Tags: java, android, string, url, symbols

I have a URL that looks like this:

Liberty%21%20ft.%20Whiskey%20Pete%20-%20Thunderfist%20%28Original%20Mix%29.mp3

I'm trying to extract just the words from it. Right now, I'm using `string.replace("%21", "!")` for each and every %20, %29, etc. because each segment represent different characters or spaces. Is there a way to just covert those symbols and numbers to what they actually mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those symbols are URLEncoded representations of characters that can't legally exist in a URL. (%20 = a single space, etc)

You need to UrlDecode those strings:

http://icfun.blogspot.com/2009/08/java-urlencode-and-urldecode-options.html

Official documentation here:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html

Answer (score 7):

It seems the input string is written using the URL encoding. Instead of writing all possible replacements manually (you can hardly cover all possibilities), you can use URLDecoder class in Java.

```
String input = "Liberty%21%20ft.%20Whiskey%20Pete...";
String decoded = URLDecoder.decode(input, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: This does not actually answer the question, as you do not explain why you suggest to use a decoder instead of string replacement and what the symbols and numbers mean.

Comment: @hotzst Sorry, I've added the explanation why I think this answer is correct. In fact it's exactly the same solution as in the accepted answer. I wrote those two lines for all those who don't want to read those external websites.